# why does lightroom5 get dark when mousing out of library pane?

Tags: lightroom

When I take my mouse out of the library pane the screen goes darker and the selected images are left bright.
I’m not sure what button I pressed to cause this. How can this be toggled off?

I thought I was typing a key word tag when the action was invoked on a particular key stroke.

Comment: ok, i think it was the letter F. It cycles through a bunch of views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have hit the L key, which invokes "lights-out" mode, darkening the UI but leaving the image bright. Pressing L repeatedly will cycle between normal, dim, and dark modes.

The F key you noted cycles between windowed and full-screen modes.